# OSX - Update "Java for OS X 2012-002" is not mentioned on support.apple.com, is this ok?

Tags: macos, security, java, updates

Straight after installing **"Java for OS X 2012-001"** Software Update asks me to install **"Java for OS X 2012-002"**, which has the exact same size (66.6 MB) and description (including the same two links: [HT5055](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5055) and [HT1222](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1222)) as the former, which strikes me as odd.

The **"Java for OS X 2012-001"** is described on the apple support pages, but the **"Java for OS X 2012-002"** is not mentioned anywhere. Also searching on google does not yield any usable results.

What is your opinon? Am i paranoid? Did you also see this update?

Answer (score 3):

Apple just issued a Mail covering "Java for OS X 2012-002", so it's legit.

[mail about the second (re-shipped) update](http://prod.lists.apple.com/archives/java-dev/2012/Apr/msg00022.html)

Answer (score 2):

I saw the 002 update, also.  Apple's SOP seems to be to admit nothing unless and until there is rolling, flaming wreckage.  So when there is an immediate update right after a corresponding normal update the safe assumption is that the first update broke something and second update (quietly) fixes it.